# replace youtibe url in my text to embed

Tags: php

I'm trying to replcae youtube url, in my text, to embed. I got it right except that I'm also print the text " https://www.youtube.com   " before the embed.
What do i nend to change?

```
return preg_replace(
    '#(http://(www.)?youtube.com)?/(v/|watch\?v\=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?#i',
    '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    $text
);
```

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://eval.in/301670 - please show us your full code.

Answer (score 0):

try this regular expression instead:

```
return preg_replace(
    '/((http(s)?:\/\/)?(www.)?youtube.com\/watch\?v=.*)/i',
    '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    $text
);
```